# How do I replace all my NULL values in a particular field in a particular table?

Tags: mysql, null, replace, phpmyadmin

I've looked all over the internet for my answer, and perhaps I'm just doing things wrong.  I have a column in my MySQL table that I need to replace all the NULL values with a text string in my SQL Query using phpMyAdmin.  I don't want the output to come out that way, I want to actually replace the null values with the text string.

I've tried

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET fieldname = replace (fieldname, "", "textstring")
```

I've read up on

```
SELECT ISNULL(field,"replacetext)
```

But this only shows the output, but doesn't actually replace it in the table.

I can't figure this out, and I've wasted so much time trying to find an answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
update tablename set fieldname = "textstring" where fieldname is null;
```

Comment: Beat me to it :) Deleting my answer.

Comment: I need 200 to get less ads (:

Comment: THANK YOU!  That was it.  I'm good at making simple things complex.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET fieldname = '' where fieldname is null
```